# jQuery getJSON problem when request is not returned as JSON

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I have the following code

```
jQuery.getJSON(encodeURI(strUrl), {address:address,state:state, zip:zip},function(data){
    alert('HELLO World!');
});
```

If for some reason the strUrl returns a string that's not in JSON format the callback function never gets called. Is there a way to know if the response is in json format or if something went wrong in the post?

Comment: I really don't think, it's a good idea to eval (and thereby execute) a result you can't trust (you don't even know, if it's syntactically correct)! It could do anything.

Comment: @chris_l Absolutely, but somethings errors occur and the expected result is in a bad format. You should prevent that from happening, that's right, but bugs exist. Remember, "in theory, practice and theory are the same; in practice, they're not". You should cover all your bases when you can.

Comment: @Seb Fully agreed, because I have exactly the same attitude on this! But in this case, it sounds to me, as if the OP *might* be just one step away from accepting anything that's syntactically correct JavaScript (even if the content is malicious). `eval` unfortuately doesn't only take JSON data, but any JavaScript. So I think, this warning is justified.

Comment: @chris_l absolutely, `eval` is baaaaad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.getJSON` doesn't allow you to define an error callback function.

You'll need to use `jQuery.ajax` instead, setting the `dataType` to `json` and set the remaining configuration variables as getJSON defines by default.

Comment: Yeah, I thought this was the only way. Ill just get the result, check if it's format is the correct and proceed. Thanks